# COUNT and SELECT query from two tables

Tags: php, sql

I have these two tables:

```
1. users
   -id
   -name
   -email
   -rank

2. pages
   -user
   -id
```

I need to select all the data from users and count how many pages did he wrote (from pages user is the id of the user from users table).

Can you make it into 1 complex query?

Comment: All the answers below use inner joins, but I suggest a `LEFT JOIN` so you get 0 for users with no pages rather than no record.

Comment: Too many good answers :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't make it into a complex query, but here's a simple one:

```
SELECT u.name, u.email, u.rank, u.id, count(p.id) as 'PageCount'
FROM Users u
JOIN Pages p ON
    p.id = u.id
GROUP BY u.name, u.email, u.rank, u.id
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, i now added another table for comments, how can i improve your query to also show the amount of comments by the user? (comments table is exactly like pages).

Comment: To do it in the same query, I'd simply add another `JOIN` to the Comment table: `JOIN Comment c ON c.id = u.id` - _but_ as @Michael says in his comment to your question I'd now use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that you get records back for all users - if you don't you'll only see the ones who have written a Page *and* a Comment.

Comment: @Widor, Kindly let me clarify myself i.e. will the query produce correct result (logically) if two users have same name?

Comment: @manurajhada As long as they have a different `id` then this query will produce one row per User (even if the `name` fields are identical).

Answer (score 3):

```
select u.*,count(p.*) from users u left join pages p on u.id=p.user group by u.id;
```

Comment: @DanBarzilay Please reconsider studying `SQL` properly, u and p are alias names for table.

Comment: so why there are also `users` and `u` here: `from users u left`

Comment: they are aliases for tables `users` and `pages`. `...from users u` creates an alias `u` for your `users` table. Same for pages

Comment: @Dan, Viswanathan is very true.. `Please reconsider studying SQL properly`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do it like this:

```
select u.id, u.name, u.email, u.rank, count(p.id) as 'counter' from users u
inner join pages p on p.user = u.id
group by u.id, u.name, u.email, u.rank
```

You group by the users info and calculate (count) the number of pages for each user.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
select   u.id, count(p.id) as 'number_of_pages_wrote'
from     users u inner join pages p
on       u.id = p.id
group by u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   users.id, users.name,users.email,users.rank, count(pages.id) 
from     users,pages 
where    users.id = pages.user 
group by users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

```
SELECT u.*, p.count
FROM users u,
     (SELECT pa.id, count(1) FROM pages pa WHERE pa.id = u.id) p
WHERE u.id = p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple query

> ```
> SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS pages FROM page GROUP BY user
> ```

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished by a `JOIN`.

For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM pages 
INNER JOIN users ON (users.id=pages.user) 
WHERE users.id=5
```

will select all pages from userid 5. I'll let you do the rest to include the aggregate function ;)